# Evaluating $x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$$

I'm getting $\displaystyle{x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+xy\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}}$. But the book says it is only $\displaystyle{xy\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}}$. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any other assumptions in your textbook?

Comment: @Mathlovin- The full question is evaluating $\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}-y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the operators as 
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} +x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \right)\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} -y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \right) =\partial_{xxyy}-y\partial_{xxy}+x\partial_{yyy}-x\partial_{y}-xy\partial_{yy}$$

Now the problem is there is nothing that cancels and reduces the solution to what you have given in the question.